# docker-compose is not setting container_name from environment variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am working on a docker-compose file, in which I need to specify **container_name** from an environment variable.

My **docker-compose.yml** file looks like this:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  jenkins:
  environment:
    - INSTANCE_NAME=team_1
  image: my_image
  container_name: container_$INSTANCE_NAME
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  expose:
    - "80"
```

So, I think, when I run **docker-compose up** it should create container as name, **container_team_1**, but instead of that it runs as **contaner_**

I also tried this thing using **.env** file, but still, I can not use environment variable in container_name,

although, if I run **docker-compose config** I can see all variables set like follow,

```
container_name: container_
environment:
  COMPANY_NAME: team_1
```

but, Actually it is not attaching in container-name.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use environment variables defined in docker-compose.yml to [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution).

Docker Compose uses **.env** by default so it should work when you define in .env file

```
INSTANCE_NAME=team_1
```

And then run `docker-compose up`

Comment: Sorry, but variable substitution get values from shell environment variables and not from **.env** file.

From the docker-compose documentation:

Compose uses the variable values from the shell environment in which docker-compose is run.

Comment: "You can set default values for environment variables using a .env file, which Compose will automatically look for. Values set in the shell environment will override those set in the .env file."

Answer (score 1):

As I can see in [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) section of the docker-compose documentation, you will need to set your `$INSTANCE_NAME` in the shell that is running the `docker-compose up`, because:

> Compose uses the variable values from the shell environment in which docker-compose is run.

First of all, do something like:

```
export INSTANCE_NAME=my_instance`
```

and then:

```
docker-compose up
```

Best regards.